# Using PG for ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am using `pg` in my application

Here is the database.yml file

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: testing_development

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

When I ran `rake db:create` this is what I got:

```
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 1: CREATE DATABASE "db/test"."sqlite3" ENCODING = 'utf8'
                             ^
: CREATE DATABASE "db/test"."sqlite3" ENCODING = 'utf8'
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When running `rake db:create`, it tries to create all the databases for you, thus you need to name your `test` and `production` databases properly. The database names can't contain periods.

I.e., if your application name is `testing`:

```
test:
  <<: *default
  database: testing_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: testing_production
```

Comment: hey thanks. Will accept your answer as soon sufficient time has elapsed.